# Solving "Robot legs" p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m with Spring IOC (DI)

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, ioc-container, guice

Using Guice, one can do the following:

```
interface Leg {}
```

_

```
class LeftLeg implements Leg {
    public String toString() {
        return "LeftLeg";
    }
}
```

_

```
class RightLeg implements Leg {
    public String toString() {
        return "RightLeg";
    }
}
```

_

```
class Robot {
    final Leg leftLeg_;
    final Leg rightLeg_;

    @Inject
    Robot(@Named("left") Leg leftLeg, @Named("right") Leg rightLeg) {
        leftLeg_ = leftLeg;
        rightLeg_ = rightLeg;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "leftLeg_=" + leftLeg_ + ", rightLeg_=" + rightLeg_;
    }
}
```

_

```
class RobotTest {
    @Test
    public void t1() throws Exception {
        Injector inj = Guice.createInjector(new AnGuiceModule());
        Robot r = inj.getInstance(Robot.class);
        assertEquals(r.toString(), "leftLeg_=LeftLeg, rightLeg_=RightLeg");
    }
}
```

_

```
class AnGuiceModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Leg.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("left")).to(LeftLeg.class);
        bind(Leg.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("right")).to(RightLeg.class);
    }
}
```

How can i achieve the same thing with Spring 3.x (3.1.x or 3.2) using JSR-330 (optional) annotations and JavaConfig without using XML configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest i could find is following (The definition of the Robot and Leg* classes does not change):

```
public class RobotTest {

    @Test
    public void t1() throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new 
               AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RobotConfig.class, Robot.class);
        Robot r = ctx.getBean(Robot.class);
        assertEquals("leftLeg_=LeftLeg, rightLeg_=RightLeg", r.toString());
    }
}

@Configuration
class RobotConfig {

    @Bean
    public Leg leftLeg() {
        return new LeftLeg();
    }

    @Bean
    public Leg rightLeg() {
        return new RightLeg();
    }

}
```

Alternative would be:

```
public class RobotTest {

    @Test public void t1() throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new 
               AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RobotConfig.class);
        Robot r = ctx.getBean(Robot.class);
        assertEquals("leftLeg_=LeftLeg, rightLeg_=RightLeg", r.toString());
    }
}

@Configuration
class RobotConfig {

   @Bean @Scope("prototype") public Robot robot() {
       return new Robot(leftLeg(), rightLeg());
   }

    @Bean @Scope("prototype") public Leg leftLeg() {
        return new LeftLeg();
    }

    @Bean @Scope("prototype") public Leg rightLeg() {
        return new RightLeg();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's crap is there really no better solution in spring? This thread from 2006 presents an interesting FactoryBean approach http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/13533-exporting-child-applicationcontext-beans-to-the-parent-applicationcontext

Answer (score 1):

`interface Leg {}`

_

```
 @Component
 class LeftLeg implements Leg {
  public String toString() {
    return "LeftLeg";
  }
 }
```

_

```
@Component
class RightLeg implements Leg {
  public String toString() {
    return "RightLeg";
 }
}
```

_

```
class Robot {
  @Autowired
  Leg leftLeg_;
  @Autowired
  Leg rightLeg_;



  public String toString() {
    return "leftLeg_=" + leftLeg_ + ", rightLeg_=" + rightLeg_;
 }
}
```

_

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
class RobotTest {
  @Autowired
  Robot r;
  @Test
  public void t1() throws Exception {
     System.out.println(r);
 }
}
```

Comment: How to do _constructor injection_? ... I corrected my question and declared the fields `final` so that is more clear that i need immutable `Robot` And also i want to use JSR-330  annotations instead of Spring specific

Comment: The other thing i don't understand in your answer is: how `leftLeg_` is bound to `class LeftLeg` and `rightLeg_` to `class RightLeg`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this; although this one uses Spring annotations, @Qualifier and @Autowired, though I don't see any reason for it not to work with @Named and @Inject as well, you should try:

```
public class MovieRecommender {

  private MovieCatalog movieCatalog;
  private CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao;

  @Autowired
  public void prepare(@Qualifier("main") MovieCatalog movieCatalog,
                      CustomerPreferenceDao customerPreferenceDao) {
      this.movieCatalog = movieCatalog;
      this.customerPreferenceDao = customerPreferenceDao;
  }

  // ...
}
```

Example taken from the [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers).

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting approach described on [spring forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/13533-exporting-child-applicationcontext-beans-to-the-parent-applicationcontext).
You need to obtain a reference to the child context somehow, I don't like the approach presented there, but I there should be other ways.

Usage:

```
  <bean name="someBean" class="playground.spring.BeanImportFactoryBean">
        <property name="applicationContext" ref="privateCtx"/>
        <property name="importBeanName" value="importBean"/>
    </bean>
```

FactoryBean code:

```
public class BeanImportFactoryBean implements FactoryBean, BeanNameAware {
    transient private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    private String beanName;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private String importBeanName;

    public BeanImportFactoryBean() {
    }

    public void setBeanName(String beanName) {
        this.beanName = beanName;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public void setImportBeanName(String importBeanName) {
        this.importBeanName = importBeanName;
    }

    protected String getUsedBeanName() {
        String returnName;
        if (importBeanName == null) {
            returnName = beanName;
        } else {
            returnName = importBeanName;
        }
        return returnName;
    }

    public Object getObject() throws Exception {
        return this.applicationContext.getBean(getUsedBeanName());
    }

    public Class getObjectType() {
        return this.applicationContext.getType(getUsedBeanName());
    }

    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return this.applicationContext.isSingleton(getUsedBeanName());
    }
}
```